# Grouping games into seasons by year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by, sum

I'm building a baseball statistics app. I'm having trouble getting games to be split into seasons.

A game has_many battings, pitchings and fieldings. A game also has a played_date field which I can get the year from.

Basically what I want to be able to do is be able to seperate games into seasons, and add up columns within that season.

For example, be able to do:

```
<% @player.each do |player| %>
    <% player.battings.seasons.each do |battingseason| %>
        <%= battingseason.total("homeruns") %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So "battingseason.total("homeruns")" would sum up the total homeruns that specific player hit within that season.

I was able to get the years of which games were played via this:

```
@game_seasons = @games.group_by { |g| g.played_date.beginning_of_year }
```

...but I'm not sure it's of so much help.

From there, I also need to be able to split seasons into fall and spring. For example, what I currently have:

```
def season
    if self.game.played_date.month >= 9 && self.game.played_date.month <= 12
        season = "fall"
    else
        season = "spring"
    end
end
```

So my problem is that I'm just not sure where to put all of this logic, in the controller, in the model? And how exactly to output it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `Season` model. The season model has one column, `season`. I would set up the models this way:

```
class Season < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
  has_many :battings, through: :games
  has_many :pitchings, through: :games
  has_many :fieldings, through: :games
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :season
end
```

You would need to add `season_id` to `games` table and you can add a `before_validate` method in the `game` model:

```
before_validate :find_or_create_season

private

def find_or_create_season
  if self.played_date.month >= 9 && self.played_date.month <= 12
    season = "fall"
  else
    season = "spring"
  end
  season_name = season + ' ' + self.played_date.year.to_s
  game_season = Season.find_or_create_by_season(season_name)
  self.season_id = game_season.id
end
```

I am not sure how you want your view to look like but this is one possibility. This will give you the summary for one player by season for homeruns:

In your controller:

```
def show
  @player = Player.find(params[:id])

  #not sure how you define if a batting was a homerun. I assumed that you have a boolean for that
  @homeruns_by_season = @player.battings.where('homerun = ?', true).group(:season).count
  #this will return a hash with season as a key and the count as the value

end
```

In your view

```
<% @homeruns_by_season.each do |season, homeruns| %>
  <td><%= season.season %></td>
  <td><%= homeruns %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So does this required creating a new table, or just a new model and a new column in the games table. Also, what are the view tags that output exactly what I want like in the example in the question. And does this do the summing for each column within battings, pitchings and fieldings? Thank you!

Comment: Yeah you would need a new `seasons` table and a new `season_id` column in the `games` table. I will update my answer to include some `view` code. Are you trying to summarize the homeruns by players or by season first. What I mean is do you want to summarize the homeruns by player first and then season or the other way around?

Comment: So let's say there are games played in 2012 and 2013. John Doe played 20 games in 2012, and he only had two games in which he hit a homerun. For the 2012 season, John Doe hit 2 homeruns. So season, then stats within a season.

Comment: AbM, this is really great. Except I have to correct the way that you did the views. If you could fix those, you're a life saver! So battings has several different columns, all of which are integers. For example: batting.single, batting.double, batting.triple. I need a way to say seasons.each do |season|, then <%= season.single %>, <%= season.double %>, etc... The hierarchy is player, games -> grouped by season, then statistic summed within that season. For each season there are multiple stats underneath battings, pitchings and fieldings to be summed. Thanks!